# Why does editing my question cause more people to see it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, bump

So I just discovered this meta site a bit ago and I must say its pretty neat having a Q&A site about a Q&A site but anyways...

My question relates back to a question I asked on Stack Overflow.  I asked the question late at night and only got a handful of views and no answers.  The next day I made a simple grammatical edit to the question and the post had two dozen views within a few minutes and I finally go my answer.  What I'd like to know is what happened to make my post so visible after my edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you edit a question, it goes back on the home page as if it were one of the newest questions.

When you first wrote the answer maybe it was a quiet time, but you edited it when lots of people were online.

Comment: If it's a very minor edit, it's shown in the front page but not necessarily at the top.

Comment: oops - corrected, thanks.

Comment: just for completeness sake: The bump is part of our review process, an edit means something changed, and bumping it to the front page is our way of saying "Hey, people, something changed here, come take a look". Most edits are good, and the extra attention translates to upvotes, but some edits are destructive and need to be dealt with asap.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos Good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you edit a post, it is published on the front page again.  We call that "bumping". Which is also a reason that minor edits are frowned upon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  And if minor edits are frowned upon, why edit my original question to drop the text were I said "Thanks" ;-)

Comment: Because signatures and thank you lines are also frowned upon, it's a gray area.

Comment: Well, IMHO, I frown upon people who don't say thanks when someone helps them out with a problem.  So thank you Gamecat for enlightening me.

Comment: On stackoverflow, we say thank you by upvoting and/or accepting.

Comment: @Freethinker The edit removing "thanks" from your question was made three minutes after you posted the question, it didn't bump it on the Meta front page as it was already there. Minor edits minutes after the question was posted are acceptable, but that's more of an exception than the rule.

Comment: @YannisRizos That's also good to know, thanks again!